# Trying to use Managed Identity with Azure Service Bus

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, azure-managed-identity

I've tried following [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-managed-service-identity) tutorial in order to authenticate my service bus against `DefaultAzureCredentials`, however, I get a 401.

I'm using the following code in the set-up:

```
services.AddAzureClients(x =>
{
    x.AddServiceBusClientWithNamespace("myns.servicebus.windows.net")
        .WithCredential(new Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential());
});
```

I then call the SB client like this:

```
var sender = client.CreateSender("myqueue");
var message = new ServiceBusMessage(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("test"));

await sender.SendMessageAsync(message);
```

When I call `SendMessageAsync` I get a 401 error:

> fail: Azure-Messaging-ServiceBus[82]
> An exception occurred while creating send link for Identifier: myqueue-578624f3-f732-4a9b-2ab0-9adc01949a5a. Error Message:
> 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Put token failed. status-code:
> 401, status-description: InvalidIssuer: Token issuer is invalid.
> TrackingId:cde3a89c-8108-48d1-8b8f-dacde18e176f,
> SystemTracker:NoSystemTracker, Timestamp:2021-05-19T07:18:44.

Before I run this, I call `az login`. I have access to the the namespace to both send and receive. My guess is that I need to allocate some kind of permission between the service bus and ... something - but since I'm running this as a console app, I'm running with my own credentials. Clearly there's something about managed identity that I don't understand.

EDIT:

Following advice from @juunas, I tried the following:

```
services.AddHostedService<ConsoleHostedService>();
services.AddAzureClients(x =>
{
    //var creds = new Azure.Identity.EnvironmentCredential(); // 1st - EnvironmentCredential authentication unavailable. Environment variables are not fully configured.'
    //var creds = new Azure.Identity.ManagedIdentityCredential(); // 2nd - No Managed Identity endpoint found
    //var creds = new Azure.Identity.SharedTokenCacheCredential(); // 3rd - 'SharedTokenCacheCredential authentication unavailable. No accounts were found in the cache.'
    //var creds = new Azure.Identity.VisualStudioCodeCredential(); // 4th - 'Stored credentials not found. Need to authenticate user in VSCode Azure Account.'
    //var creds = new Azure.Identity.AzureCliCredential(); // 5th
    var creds = new Azure.Identity.DefaultAzureCredential();
    
    x.AddServiceBusClientWithNamespace("myns.servicebus.windows.net")
        .WithCredential(creds);
```

Comment: Your code is failing when you run it in cloud or is it failing locally as well?

Comment: Try to use specific credential and then check whether still get 401.

Comment: Have you tried to assigned `Azure Service Bus Data Sender` to the MSI at the namespace level?

Comment: @GauravMantri - this is locally only

Comment: @JimXu - yes, I have granted the data sender privilege

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It says the "token issuer is invalid".
That means it got an access token, but it was issued by the wrong Azure AD tenant.
The Az CLI allows you to specify the Azure AD tenant id with the `-t tenant-id-here` argument on `az login`.

`DefaultAzureCredential` could also be using some other credential (it attempts multiple credentials like VisualStudioCredential before the AzureCliCredential).
You could instead try to use `AzureCliCredential` directly and see if it works.
That of course won't use Managed Identity so you'd need to use `ChainedTokenCredential` with the AZ CLI credential + ManagedIdentityCredential to support both.

Comment: `AzureCliCredential` works - but I'm a little confused as to why.  Also, if it is what I suspect, then my assumption was that `DefaultAzureCredential` did what you've described in ChainedTokenCredential ... ?

Comment: It tries a bunch of credentials and my guess is one of the others before Azure CLI succeeds (VS / SharedTokenCache etc.), but then returns a token for the wrong tenant.

Comment: I tried every credential specifically in order (listed here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet).  I would have thought that one of them would give me the same error that I got from DefaultAzureCredential, but they didn't - I got a different error from each one (except Cli)

Comment: Okay, that's weird.. What error did you get from them?

Comment: Have you tried `VisualStudioCredential`? That was missing from your list but is used by DefaultAzureCredential. You can see the created credentials in the source: https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/748df71998927c7618f657cded2ed0648e24c9b3/sdk/identity/Azure.Identity/src/DefaultAzureCredential.cs#L191

Comment: Yes - thankyou!  That was it.  It wasn't in the docs, but that was causing the issue.  Thanks for all your help!

Comment: Excellent :) With some of the credentials you can give options to define e.g. what tenant you want to use. DefaultAzureCredential accepts those options too.