# Azure Service Bus managed identity in Visual Studio returning 401 - Token issuer is invalid

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

I'm attempting to access Azure Service Bus using a managed identity from my code. At the moment I'm just trying this locally.

When I debug my code I get the following error

`System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Put token failed. status-code: 401, status-description: InvalidIssuer: Token issuer is invalid`

Here is my service bus instance

[image]

Here is my user with `Azure Service Bus Data Owner` permissions

[image]

And here is my code

```cs
_client = new ServiceBusClient("oconnorevents.servicebus.windows.net", new DefaultAzureCredential());
```

I am logged into Visual Studio as the same user added to the service bus. I also tried logging in via the CLI but it didn't help.

Where am I going wrong here?

I've looked at this similar recent question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67598663/trying-to-use-managed-identity-with-azure-service-bus) but the solutions proposed didn't work for me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you use `DefaultAzureCredential` to auth, it will try several credential types to auth as mentioned [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.defaultazurecredential?view=azure-dotnet), one of them is [`VisualStudioCredential`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.visualstudiocredential?view=azure-dotnet), but it will auth to the home AAD tenant of the user logged in VS, in your case, I suppose the service bus is in a subscription which is not under the home tenant of the user.

I can also reproduce your issue on my side.

[image]

To solve the issue, just use `VisualStudioCredential` directly, then simply specify the `TenantId` via [`VisualStudioCredentialOptions`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.visualstudiocredentialoptions?view=azure-dotnet), then it will work fine.

**Sample:**

To find the `TenantId`, just navigate to the `Azure Active Directory` which **the subscription of your service bus located**.

[image]

```
TokenCredential tokenCredential = new VisualStudioCredential(new VisualStudioCredentialOptions {TenantId = "xxxxxxx" });
ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient("xxx.servicebus.windows.net", tokenCredential);
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for that. It did work with the specifics but I don't see a reason why it wouldn't work generally. I only have 1 subscription where everything lives, including service bus.

Comment: I was attempting to do this with DefaultAzureCredential and getting 401.  Thanks for the clear solution.

Answer (score 10):

Since I have access to several different tenants, Visual Studio sometimes gets confused.  Another way you can handle this is to continue to use the DefaultAzureCredential, but to give Visual Studio a hint about which tenant to use.
[image]
First left click the your project and examine the properties and then:

1. Left-click "Debug"
2. Left-click the "Add" button to add an environment variable
3. For name use "AZURE_TENANT_ID" and for value use your tenant id. Yes, that is a bogus tenant id in the picture :-)

Reference

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.identity.environmentcredential?view=azure-dotnet
- https://damienbod.com/2020/10/09/using-key-vault-certificates-with-microsoft-identity-web-and-asp-net-core-applications/

Answer (score 8):

Specify the exact tenant id by adding the following key to local.settings.json.

```
"AZURE_TENANT_ID": "your tenant id"
```

[image]

I tried to create an azure function that receives messages from a service bus queue using a managed identity trigger and it worked for me.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

late to the party but I got it working on my local Visual Studio with this code

```
var tokenCredential = new VisualStudioCredential(new VisualStudioCredentialOptions { TenantId = "xxx-xxx" });

ServiceBusClient client = new ServiceBusClient("my-name-space.servicebus.windows.net", tokenCredential);

sender = client.CreateSender('my-topic');

var msgBody = new Person{ Name = 'joe'};

await sender.SendMessageAsync(new ServiceBusMessage(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(msgBody)));
```

Also, remember to sign in to Azure in your Visual Studio,
and assign your account to the role "Azure Service bus Data Sender" , see below:

[image]